# Recommendation for good papers on prime numbers.

Tags: soft-question, prime-numbers, self-learning

I am looking forward to read some good papers on prime numbers. I am interested in studying sums/products involving prime numbers. It would be really good if the paper concentrates on the same. I know elementary number theory.

Comment: This question is way way WAY too broad.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas–Lehmer_primality_test

Comment: I recommend to you, this published by MAA: Zagier, *Newman's Short Proof of the Prime Number Theorem*, The American Mathematical Monthly, Vol. 104, No. 8 (1997). You need to have knowledges of analytic number theory, but I belive that is the best for you due the quality of the paper. Good luck

Comment: This isn't similar, currently I believe that you can find a version from arXiv: Sondow, *Ramanujan Primes and Bertrand's Postulate*, The American Mathematical Monthly Vol. 116, No. 7 (2009), pp. 630-635.

Answer (score 4):

These are some website links/notes that can help you:

$1$. [Prime numbers from Wolfram Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/search/index.html?query=prime%20numbers&collection=mathworld)

$2$.[William Stein: Elementary number theory, Chapter 1 (Prime Numbers)](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiJ9rnulufQAhXET7wKHSenAasQFggvMAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwstein.org%2Fent%2Fent.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEFzblQIqhHeuOQD7cfNTCxKOMSsA&sig2=n3F2Tx7BsZo-g9iNdOA6CQ).

$3$.[View Questions with the tag "Prime Numbers on MSE"](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=prime%20numbers).

$4$. Last but not the least: 
 [The prime page](https://primes.utm.edu/).